# Implement UIAlertView into a Tabbed Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, reachability

I have finally gotten code for displaying an alert if there is no internet connection.

```
 Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"m.google.com"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
if(internetStatus == NotReachable){

    NSLog(@"There's no connection");

    UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"No internet connection"
                                   message:@"Internet connection is required to use this app"
                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [errorAlertView show];

}else
    NSLog(@"Internet connection is OK");
```

It doesn't work when a WebView is in a tabbed application. Is there anyway I could tweak the code to get it to be friendly with a WebView in a Tabbed View Controller?

Comment: How is the posted code related to a web view and/or a tab view?

Comment: If there is no internet connection for the web view, there should be an alert

Comment: Main question is - where do You call this function? Maybe it is simply not called? Do You get out either of those NSLog messages? if not, then probably this functionality is not called at all.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to setup an evented reachability listener, instead of just checking at the random moment the app is launched. Since your network connection may drop in and out several times during the lifecycle of your app. I use this open source one as a CocoaPod: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. I created a UITabBarController file, and put the code into there, so every time I open the app, if there is no internet connection, I'll get the alert.